# Implementing my own ESC (electronic speed controller)?

Tags: motor-controller

I have a project that uses an ESC to run a brushless motor (Hobbyist RC plane sized, 24 gram, 1300-1500 KV).

I would like to experiment with eliminating the ESC and driving the motor with my own circuitry and control software.  Are there any good tutorials or other starting points?

(I realize it's more practical to just keep using my $8 ESC, but I'm interested in this as a learning exercise.)

Comment: This is for Electronic Speed Control?

Comment: What type of motor are you wanting to drive? (I.e.: amperage, wattage.)

Comment: @tyblu, yes electronic speed controller for RC plane sized brushless motor. (updated question to reflect)

Comment: related: [Controlling small brushless dc motors?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34823/controlling-small-brushless-dc-motors).

Comment: Afaik there is a AVR application note with code and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an introduction to electronic speed control systems: http://www.stefanv.com/electronics/escprimer.html

Actual design depends on the type of motor you want to drive. A 300A high-torque gear motor is much different from those tiny featherweight propeller motors. At the heavy-duty end of the scale (300A) is something like this: [Open Source Motor Control](http://www.robotpower.com/products/osmc_info.html). All designs are online and there are a few articles explaining what the heck is going on. At the other end of the scale are small prop motors, like those in the [MikroKopter](http://www.mikrokopter.com/ucwiki/en/BrushlessCtrl).

Comment: That MikroKopter link is pretty slick. The bare PCB price is reasonable, but the shipping is pretty high. The US site has the ESC assembled... not sure if that's defeating the purpose of your question...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PICs (e.g. http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en012037) or I think the Arduino crowd is doing this too.